# How can query ALL iTunes store fronts of all countries?

Tags: api, itunes, country, storefront

I have an iTunes appID of 9 digits.

When I query itunes with a US store
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id508611913
it does not work.

When I try it with a Great Britain (UK) store front
http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/id508611913
then it works.

If i try it without any country designation, it defaults to US
so it does not find it.

I want to query ALL the countries at once.
Does Apple provide an API that can query across all the countries?

Thanks

Comment: Probably not, but it seems like something you could write with an array of country codes, and a loop hitting url of the server for each country code in that array

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "no."

Apple does provide an API (http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) but each query is storefront specific so, as mentioned in the first answer from Stuart, you'll need to cycle through each country.

We also have an API for our clients that may be of interest for you.  It's what powers our "Availability Tool" (http://www.georiot.com/availability).

Comment: Availability tool looks awesome