# Get all Country and Code of iTunes Stores

Tags: ios, itunes, country-codes

I would like to have a list of Countries and their corresponding Codes used in iTunes, so that I can query them in iTunes API.

Thanks

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105638/how-can-query-all-itunes-store-fronts-of-all-countries, you have to query them one by one.

Comment: I like to display a list of iTunes Stores countries and then the user can select their country and then search for keywords.

Comment: for complete list available you can check this - http://www.apple.com/choose-your-country/, but using API i won't think its possible.

Answer (score 0):

(Posting an answer to an 11-year-old question since I spent quite some time figuring this out recently.)

Apple has an internal web API to get all iTunes storefronts, including their IDs, country codes, and available languages. A dynamically updated list such as this one is useful since Apple onboards new countries to its cloud services from time to time.

https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/availableStoreFronts

Do not open this URL in a web browser! If the user agent is a web browser, the server will return HTML that tries to open the iTunes app.

The server should return a property list file. For example, see [here](https://gist.github.com/fumoboy007/a1872bc894b0a851d7de74f754253bf8).